# A type that can hold both Foo* and std::shared_ptr<Foo>

Tags: c++, c++17

What's the most convenient way to be able to store either std::shared_ptr or Foo* in the same type?

```
Foo* a = ...;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> b = ...;

Bar c = a; // Success, Bar type can hold Foo*
Bar d = b; // Success, Bar type can also hold std::shared_ptr<Foo>
```

std::variant<Foo*, std::shared_ptr< Foo>> is okay, but it's not possible to dereference it directly and that is kind of annoying. Is there a better way?

Comment: Give `Bar` a constructor that takes a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`?

Comment: What would be the ownership semantics of the type `Bar`? A raw pointer has no clear ownership semantics, whereas a `shared_ptr` signals shared ownershop (and atuomagic lifetime management via its underlying automatic reference counting).

Comment: Bar type is what I'm looking for, sorry if that's not clear.

Comment: Bar type should not change the ownership semantics of the underlying pointer.

Comment: Is a `Bar` objects stores a `Foo*` (raw pointer), does it own the resource it (possibly) points to? Or is a `Bar` just an observer or it, relying on the grace of someone else to handle that resource (however without deleting it before `Bar` is done with it)?

Comment: Bar should be an observer in this case.

Comment: Not every day that you see five different answers from five of the high-end C++ gold badge users to the same questions, within an hour at that. Favouriting.

Comment: @VladimirBogachev: You really should reconsider structuring your code in a way that requires this. The hypothetical `Bar` in your example doesn't have a clear ownership relationship to the `Foo` it owns. Therefore, it is unclear as to what the legal uses of `Bar` will be. If you give it an unowned pointer, when is it OK for you to delete it, for example. The desire for such a type is indicative of structural problems in your code.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.

While it is rarely useful, you can in fact construct a non-owning non-counting `std::shared_ptr`:

```
auto p = std::shared_ptr<Foo>{std::shared_ptr<void>(), raw_pointer};
```

---

If you want to cater to weird people disrespecting the abstraction (looking at the reference-counts, to be specific), you could also stash an eternal anchor somewhere and use that:

```
struct pass_t {
    template <class... T>
    constexpr int operator()(T&&...) noexcept
    { return 0; }
};
constexpr inline pass_t pass;

inline const std::shared_ptr<void> anchor {nullptr, pass};

auto p = std::shared_ptr<Foo>{anchor, raw_pointer};
```

Comment: Nice exploit of the aliasing constructor there. I can't think of what the corner cases you mention could be, though.

Comment: @Quentin If someone explicitly looks at the reference-counts, they can become very confused...

Answer (score 3):

You can just wrap `std::variant<Foo*, std::shared_ptr< Foo>>` in something that does the right dereferencing

```
class Bar
{
public:
    explicit Bar(Foo* foo) : foo(foo) {}
    explicit Bar(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) : foo(foo) {}

    Foo& operator*() const { return std::visit(deref, foo); }
    Foo* operator->() const { return std::visit(arrow, foo); }

private:
    struct {
        Foo& operator()(Foo* f) { return *f; }
        Foo& operator()(std::shared_ptr<Foo> f) { return *f; }
    } deref;

    struct {
        Foo* operator()(Foo* f) { return f; }
        Foo* operator()(std::shared_ptr<Foo> f) { return f.get(); }
    } arrow;

    std::variant<Foo*, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foo;
};
```

Comment: The `Bar` operators are missing `return` statements when calling `std::visit()`

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same as [Caleth's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687355/3233393), but more generic and exposing the variant nature of that new type:

```
template <class... PointerTypes>
struct PointerHolder : std::variant<PointerTypes...> {
    using std::variant<PointerTypes...>::variant;
    
    auto *operator -> () const {
        return &operator*();
    }
    
    auto &operator * () const {
        return std::visit([](auto const &p) -> auto & { return *p; }, *this);
    }
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sdNWbcm2siw1lei9)

Comment: `&operator->();` ??

Comment: @Caleth derp. I also rewrote it the other way around just so it's a bit less roundabout than effectively `*&*actualPointer`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `shared_ptr` to hold both the unowned `Foo*` and the owned `Foo*`.  You choose which is which by using a custom deleter that does nothing:

```
struct not_owned
{
    void
    operator()(void*) const
    {
    }
};


Foo f;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp{&f, not_owned{}};  // sp doesn't own the pointer
sp = std::make_shared<Foo>();              // sp does own the pointer
```

Comment: Careful to only do this inside some wrapper, though, or it'll be produce copies of `sp` that you think are refcounted but aren't, and whoops leak

Comment: That's pretty clever. You could also make `not_owned` a simple function (and pass it as-is, of course).

Answer (score 2):

variant might work with some helpers.

```
template<class X>
struct is_variant: std::false_type{};
template<class...Ts>
struct is_variant< std::variant<Ts...> >:std::true_type{};
template<class X>
constexpr bool is_variant_v = is_variant<X>{};

template<class F>
struct variant_method {
  F f;
  template<class Variant> requires (is_variant_v<std::decay_t<Variant>>)
  friend auto operator->*( Variant && variant, variant_method const& self ) {
    return [&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
      return std::visit( [&](auto&& val)->decltype(auto) {
        return self.f( decltype(val)(val), decltype(args)(args)... );
      }, std::forward<Variant>(variant) );
    };
  }
};
template<class F>
variant_method(F&&)->variant_method<std::decay_t<F>>;
```

now we can do this:

```
constexpr variant_method dereference{ [](auto&& x)->decltype(auto) { return *x; } };
template<class T>
constexpr variant_method operator_{ [](auto&& x)->T { return static_cast<T>(x); } };
constexpr auto to_bool = operator_<bool>;
```

and here we go!

```
struct something {
  int x = 0;
};

std::variant<std::shared_ptr<something>, something*> some_ptr;

some_ptr = new something;
if ((some_ptr->*to_bool)())
  (some_ptr->*dereference)().x = 7;

some_ptr = std::make_shared<something>();

if ((some_ptr->*to_bool)())
  (some_ptr->*dereference)().x = 3;
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/oGWWas).

Now we can wrap it up pretty

```
template<class...Ts>
struct variant_ptr:std::variant<Ts...> {
  using base = std::variant<Ts...>;
  using base::base;

  auto& operator*() const { return (((base const&)*this)->*dereference)(); }
  auto& operator*() { return (((base&)*this)->*dereference)(); }

  auto* get() const { return std::addressof(**this); }
  auto* get() { return std::addressof(**this); }

  auto* operator->() const { return get(); }
  auto* operator->() { return get(); }

  explicit operator bool() const { return (((base const&)*this)->*to_bool)(); }
};
```

now we do this:

```
variant_ptr<Foo*, std::shared_ptr<Foo>>
```

and everything "just works".

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/bzje8f).

Of course we can skip all of the `variant_method` stuff above and just implement `std::visit` in our `variant_ptr`.

Oh, and [here is a version that gets rid of those `base&` casts](https://godbolt.org/z/neqzYT) by teaching `variant_method::operator->*` all about interacting with derived-from-variant types.

```
template<class...Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_variant_base(std::variant<Ts...> const& x) { return x; }
template<class...Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_variant_base(std::variant<Ts...>& x) { return x; }
template<class...Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_variant_base(std::variant<Ts...>&& x) { return std::move(x); }

constexpr auto get_variant_base_lambda = [](auto&&x)->decltype(get_variant_base(decltype(x)(x))){ return get_variant_base(decltype(x)(x)); };

template<class X>
constexpr bool is_variant_derived_v = std::is_invocable_v< decltype(get_variant_base_lambda), X >;

template<class F>
struct variant_method {
  F f;
  template<class Variant> requires (is_variant_derived_v<Variant>)
  friend auto operator->*( Variant && variant, variant_method const& self ) {
    return [&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
      return std::visit( [&](auto&& val)->decltype(auto) {
        return self.f( decltype(val)(val), decltype(args)(args)... );
      }, get_variant_base(std::forward<Variant>(variant)) );
    };
  }
};

template<class...Ts>
struct variant_ptr:std::variant<Ts...> {
  using base = std::variant<Ts...>;
  using base::base;

  auto& operator*() const { return ((*this)->*dereference)(); }
  auto& operator*() { return ((*this)->*dereference)(); }

  auto* get() const { return std::addressof(**this); }
  auto* get() { return std::addressof(**this); }

  auto* operator->() const { return get(); }
  auto* operator->() { return get(); }

  explicit operator bool() const { return ((*this)->*to_bool)(); }
};
```

Comment: I don't want to sound out of character, but isn't this a tad overkill? What's could be an advantage to having these `variant_method`s around?

Comment: @Quentin Why write narrow code when you can implement a modest language extension as a 20 line library.  They are method pointers that work on variants, and are about as generic as you can get.  I mean, try implementing polymorphism with a closed set of derived types in your `variant<Ts*...>`; now do `(var->*operator_<Base*>)()`.  Lots of fun stuff falls out; everything they do can be done with `visit`, but I find you think about it differently when you are using and writing variant member function pointers.

Comment: So basically, this emulates adding "passthrough" methods to `std::variant` from the outside. Eh, why not. I'm not convinced the insane call syntax would make them viable without the wrapper though. Edit: live-reloading of comment edits would be great :)

Comment: @Quentin It is standard member function pointer call syntax.  You can make `var->*mem_ptr(args...)` work without much work, but order of operations makes that not work with "real" member functions, so I'm of two minds.  Oh, and as a bonus fun bit, you can modify `variant_method` into `any_method` and support it on an extended `std::any`, but that gets into serious overkill (and that is by measures of overkill where the above is 1 unit of overkill).

Comment: Yeah, it's not so much insane as just clunky. I personally sigh everytime I have to parenthesize `->*` and its weird precedence.